# R script does not run in RStudio, but runs in the original console?

Tags: r, rstudio

These days, I have a problem with R and RStudio. The R script cannot run in RStudio, it often is interrupted. But it can successfully run in the original console. Here is the script:

```
library(MASS)
simulation <- function(index) { 
n = 800  #100 200 400 800 1600 3200
 p = 0.5 * n  #0.5*n 0.8*n 1.2*n
  delta = 0.5  #0.5
  k0 = 1
  y = array(0, dim = c(p, n))
  # simulation1 r=3
  # ---------------------------------------------------------
  r = 4
  A = array(runif(p * r, min = -1, max = 1), dim = c(p, r))
  x = array(0, dim = c(r, n))  #x = array(0, dim = c(p, n)) 
  epsilon = array(t(mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0, p), Sigma = diag(1, p, p))), 
                  dim = c(p, n))
  e = array(t(mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0, r), Sigma = diag(1, r, r))), dim = c(r, 
                                                                          n))
  Pi = diag(c(0.6, -0.5, 0.3, 0.6), r, r)
  for (i in 2:n) {
    x[, i] = Pi %*% x[, i - 1, drop = FALSE] + e[, i]
  }
  A[, 2] = A[, 2]/p^(delta/2)  # weak factor
  y1 = A %*% x + epsilon
  y = t(scale(t(y1), center = T, scale = FALSE))
  Mhat = array(0, dim = c(p, p))
  for (i in 1:k0) {
    covk = y[, (i + 1):n, drop = FALSE] %*% t(y[, 1:(n - i), drop = FALSE])/(n - 
                                                                               i)
    Mhat = Mhat + covk %*% t(covk)
  }
  R = p/2
  ratio = array(0, dim = c(R, 1))
  temp = eigen(Mhat)
  value = temp$values
  vector = temp$vectors
  for (i in 1:R) {
    ratio[i] = value[i + 1]/value[i]
  }
  plot(ratio, type = "l")
  rhat1 = which.min(ratio)
  Ahat1 = vector[, 1:rhat1, drop = FALSE]
  # two step
  ystar = y1 - Ahat1 %*% t(Ahat1) %*% y1
  ystar = t(scale(t(ystar), center = T, scale = FALSE))
  Mhatstar = array(0, dim = c(p, p))
  for (i in 1:k0) {
    covk = ystar[, (i + 1):n, drop = FALSE] %*% t(ystar[, 1:(n - i), 
                                                        drop = FALSE])/(n - i)
    Mhatstar = Mhatstar + covk %*% t(covk)
  }
  temp1 = eigen(Mhatstar)
  valuestar = temp1$values
  vector1 = temp1$vectors
  ratiostar = array(0, dim = c(R, 1))
  for (i in 1:R) {
    ratiostar[i] = valuestar[i + 1]/valuestar[i]
  }
  plot(ratiostar, type = "l")
  rhat2 = which.min(ratiostar)
  # Ahat2 = vector1[, 1:rhat2, drop = FALSE]
  rhat = rhat1 + rhat2
  # Ahat = cbind2(Ahat1, Ahat2)
  return(rhat)
}
result=replicate(200,simulation())
```

The program is often interrupted. I do not know why.

My desktop is : win7
RStudio version :0.98.426
The log file is :

```
15 Oct 2013 11:02:50 [rsession-Administrator] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<session::HttpConnection>, boost::function<void()>) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:146
15 Oct 2013 11:03:00 [rsession-Administrator] ERROR r error 5 (R symbol not found) [symbol (option)=ggvis.renderer]; OCCURRED AT: T r::options::getOption(const std::string&, const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >] C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\r\include/r/ROptions.hpp:73; LOGGED FROM: T r::options::getOption(const std::string&, const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >] C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\r\include/r/ROptions.hpp:75
```

Comment: Might be better to take this to http://support.rstudio.org/

Comment: Runs fine for me in Rstudio 0.97.551... 400 plots, brill

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There are lots of parts to this script.  To make it easier to diagnose the problem, you need to find the simplest script that causes the problem.

Comment: Splitting up into several functions would also help in readability.